# Access Child nodes with namespace using xpath

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

How can I read the content of the childnotes using Xpath?

I have already tried this:

```
var xml = new XmlDocument();
            
xml.Load("server-status.xml");
var ns = new XmlNamespaceManager(xml.NameTable);
ns.AddNamespace("ns", "namespace");
var node = xml.SelectSingleNode("descendant::ns:server[ns:ip-address]", ns)
Console.WriteLine(node.InnerXml)
```

But I only get a string like this:

```
<ip-address>127.0.0.50</ip-address><name>Server 1</name><group>DATA</group>
```

How can I get the values individually?

Xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<server-status xmlns="namespace">
    <server>
        <ip-address>127.0.0.50</ip-address>
        <name>Server 1</name>
        <group>DATA</group>
    </server>
</server-status>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using XML namespaces in XPath correctly.

However, your original XPath,

```
descendant::ns:server[ns:ip-address]
```

says to select all `ns:server` elements with `ns:ip-address` children.

If you wish to select the `ns:ip-address` children themselves, instead use

```
descendant::ns:server/ns:ip-address
```

Similarly, you could select `ns:name` or `ns:group` elements.